# Change URL in jsf

Tags: jsf, url

Following link is running

```
    http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/htmlPages/login.xhtml
```

Here My Project is about to completed in JSF but now I need to remove "htmlPages" from this URL.

JSF provides any functionality like this ?

Comment: Huh? Just get rid of that folder in your project structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PrettyFaces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) for URL rewrite.

Comment: is it possible without using any library ?

Comment: You're better off using PrettyFaces; anything else will require unwieldy custom code

Answer (score 0):

You can implement view resolver filter. That filter check if your url contains your views folder `WEB-INF/htmlPages/` prefix in url. If doesn't, then redirect to url with that prefix, so you can using urls without `htmlPages` directly.

Hope this helps

```java
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ViewResolverFilter implements Filter {

    public static final String WEB_VIEWS_PREFIX = "/htmlPages/";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {  }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String requestURI = httpRequest.getRequestURI();
        String path = requestURI.substring(httpRequest.getContextPath().length());

        if (!path.startsWith(WEB_VIEWS_PREFIX)) {
            String newURI = WEB_VIEWS_PREFIX + path;
            request.getRequestDispatcher(newURI).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }
}
```

and register that filter in your `web.xml`:

```xml
<filter>
        <filter-name>viewResolverFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>ViewResolverFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>viewResolverFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: So every link requested in OP's application will have `WEB_VIEWS_PREFIX` appended?

Comment: No. This filter is using forward not redirect. URL will remain untouched. But i change a little bit this example and filter should be mapped only for /*.xhtml in `url-pattern`. But after all, would be better use PrettyFaces, like i wrote in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a servlet to forward all old urls like this:

```java
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/htmlPages/*")
public class FServlet extends HttpServlet{

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getPathInfo()).forward (req, resp);
}

}
```

Assuming targeted views match the same path without *htmlPages*.